# Cleaner way to add both static and variable class in html in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular

It could be silly but how do I do something like this in angular 2 in a cleaner way? (Avoiding the string concatenation)

```
<div [class]="'indicator indicator-circle ' + colorClass"></div>
```

**Explanation :**
I want to add two static classes `indicator` & `indicator-circle` at all times but I also want the `colorClass` to be applied which is an input from the component class.

Answer (score 6):

You could leverage the `ngClass` directive with an array:

```
<div [ngClass]="['indicator', 'indicator-circle', colorClass]"></div>
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngClass`

```
<div class="indicator indicator-circle" [ngClass]="colorClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put only `colorClass` in `[ngClass]/[attr.class]/[class]` property binding

```
<div class="indicator indicator-circle" [ngClass]="colorClass"></div>
```